# Lombok equals and hash code on inherited classes with callsuper=true

Tags: lombok

I'm trying to understand how the lombok equals object method works for inherited classes.  I've looked at [this](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) and still don't entirely understand ...

If I create this single class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class EntityCombined {

    @Builder.Default
    private List<@Valid EntityFour> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Size(min = 5)
    private String a;

    @NotNull
    private EntityThree.Type b;
    @NotNull
    private String           c;
    @CountryCode2
    private String    d;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   e;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   f;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   g;

    public enum Type {
        Q, W, E, R, T, Y
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Builder
    public static
    class EntityFour {
        @NotNull
        private String  a;
        @CountryCode2
        private String  b;
        @NotNull
        private boolean c;
    }
}
```

everything works as I would expect and

```
final EntityCombined ec1 = StaticContentProvider.createEntityCombined();
final EntityCombined ec2 = StaticContentProvider.createEntityCombined();
final EntityCombined ec3 = StaticContentProvider.createAnotherEntityCombined();

//pass
assertEquals(ec1.hashCode(), ec2.hashCode());
assertEquals(ec1, ec2);
assertTrue(ec1.equals(ec2));

//fail
assertEquals(ec1.hashCode(), ec3.hashCode());
assertEquals(ec1, ec3);
assertTrue(ec1.equals(ec3));
```

However if I split it into an inherited class structure like this (I commented out the inner class to check it wasn't the issue)

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class EntityTwo extends EntityOne {

    private String p;

//    @Builder.Default
//    private List<@Valid EntityFour> aList = new ArrayList<>();

//    @AllArgsConstructor
//    @NoArgsConstructor
//    @Data
//    @Builder
//    public static
//    class EntityFour {
//        @NotNull
//        private String  a;
//        @CountryCode2
//        private String  b;
//        @NotNull
//        private boolean c;
//    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class EntityOne {

    @Size(min = 5)
    private String a;

    @NotNull
    private Type b;
    @NotNull
    private String    c;
    @CountryCode2
    private String    d;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   e;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   f;
    @NotNull
    private boolean   g;

    public enum Type {
        Q, W, E, R, T, Y
    }
}
```

and initialise like this

```
final EntityTwo local21 = new EntityTwo().builder()
        .a("hello")
        .b(EntityTwo.Type.Q)
        .e(true)
        .f(true)
        .g(true)
        .c("qwasty")
        .d("Let's be avenue")
        .build();
final EntityTwo local22 = new EntityTwo().builder()
        .a("hello")
        .b(EntityTwo.Type.Q)
        .e(true)
        .f(true)
        .g(true)
        .c("qwasty")
        .d("Let's be avenue")
        .build();;
final EntityTwo local23 = new EntityTwo().builder()
        .a("diff")
        .b(EntityTwo.Type.Q)
        .e(true)
        .f(true)
        .g(true)
        .c("qwasty")
        .d("Let's be avenue")
        .build();
```

then with callsuper = true the same objects don't match

```
assertEquals(local21.hashCode(), local22.hashCode());
assertEquals(local21, local22);
assertTrue(local21.equals(local22));
```

all fail.

If I set callSuper = false then they all match (unless I set p to be different).  That makes sense to me but I don't understand why with callsuper = true it is not just treating them as a 'flat class' like EntityCombined?

I can define my own equals operators and so this is not a big issue but I would like to understand why they don't match, or to know if I'm getting the config wrong in some way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `@EqualsAndHashCode` on `EntityOne`. That means `EntityOne` uses the `equals` logic from `Object`, which simply checks for referential equality. That means that two different objects will always be not equal, even if they share the same field values. The lombok-generated `equals()` in `EntityTwo` calls `EntityOne::equals` because you told lombok so by `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)`. (Remember that lombok's code only deals with content from the annotated class, i.e., `equals()` only compares the fields from the annotated class, not the fields from the superclass.)

Just add `@EqualsAndHashCode` to `EntityOne` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Yes thanks.  I was just logging in to delete the question!